# Installer stopping service and giving file in use warning

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX installer project which installs a client app and a windows service. It is set to stop the service during install. However it still shows the error window:

> The following applications are using files which the installer must update

with the `Try Again`, `Continue` and `Cancel` options. If I choose `Continue` and inspect the windows event logs for the installer it shows the service being stopped and started again. The StopServices element is in the recommended sequence position.

How can I avoid the error window?

My understanding is that it doesn't matter what order the files are listed as windows installer stops the service before copying any of them. I had wondered whether the service exe needed to be listed first.

Comment: Your service may be crashing in it's stop handler, and have a recovery step to restart itself.

Comment: Do you have Wait=yes for the service control?

Comment: Yes, Wait = yes. And it does stop according to the logs, just after it displays the windows saying files are in use. And if I stop the service manually it always stops very fast, so I don't *think* it is crashing. But I will investigate that further.

Comment: Having a service stop according to a log just means that the process has completed the service sutdown protocol. It does not mean that the process has gone away yet, so it can still hold files in use. Also, if there are any handles open to the service or the process that can affect things because the service or process can't yet be completely discarded. These issue are nearly always something related to the code in the service.

Comment: OK - I will investigate the service further. It might be a while before I get a result - but I will come back with a result when I can.

Comment: @DaleBurrell - I'm having similar issues. It has been a while ;-) Any insights?

Comment: Lots of insights :) firstly in an ideal world one uses the "ServiceInstall" and "ServiceControl" elements to control service install, and start and stop. They work well, but when I investigated my application further (which I had inherited) it turns out that it used custom actions before and after install to manually stop and start the service, and for compability reasons I was unable to change that. However the issue I had was as @PhilDW pointed to, the service wasn't actually shutting down within the required timeframe due to an exception during shutdown. (Out of space).

Comment: Finally, as best as I can tell the installer checks whether files are in use first, and in our case we shut the service and app down in custom code - but that was run after the check for files in use, so the install actually still succeeded without needing a reboot, even though it showed the annoying error. And when run using msiexec.exe on silent mode it just worked. So many factors :) Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution: Use the "ServiceInstall" and "ServiceControl" elements to ensure the service is stopped/started (and installed/uninstalled) correctly.

In fact in our installer the app and service were being stopped/started from within custom installer code. However the check for whether the files are in use occurs before the custom installer code is run. So the files are in use when the installer starts, but are not in use by the time the installer attempts to copy the files. So annoying to the user, but not actually an issue. And if installed using `msiexec.exe` in quiet mode then the install succeeds.

Furthermore we had another issue with the service returned from the shutdown call, prior to actually having shutdown. (As commented by @PhilDW).